# Inconsistent results when scrolling List

Tags: listview, swiftui

this is my model:

```
struct ResultsModel: Codable, Identifiable {
let id = UUID()
let rank: Int
let name: String
let teamPublishID: String
let amountOfMatches: Int
let wins: Int
let loses: Int
let draws: Int

var points: String {
    get {
        return "W:\(wins) L:\(loses) D:\(draws)"
    }
   }
}
```

and corresponding swiftui view:

```
import SwiftUI
struct DisplayMatchResultsIcons {
    let model: ResultsModel
}

extension DisplayMatchResultsIcons: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack (spacing: -1.0){
                ForEach(0..<model.wins) {_ in
                    Image(systemName: "w.square.fill")
                        .imageScale(.medium)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
            }
                ForEach(0..<model.loses) {_ in
                    Image(systemName: "l.square.fill")
                        .imageScale(.medium)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
            }

            ForEach(0..<model.draws) {_ in
                    Image(systemName: "d.square.fill")
                        .imageScale(.medium)
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it should show a colored bar like this:

[image: Results]

My problem is that I don't get consistent results. For the results displayed when the application starts all is alright, but as soon as I start scrolling, it shows nonsense. I created a helper function points to check if the data are correct and indeed they are.
I also get an error in the console which I don't get or don't know how to implement:

```
ForEach<Range<Int>, Int, ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Image, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Scale>>, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>> count (2) != its initial count (3). `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id`!


struct DisplayResultsTable{
    @StateObject var resultsTableSupport: ResultsTableSupport

}

extension DisplayResultsTable: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(resultsTableSupport.results.nameOfCompetition)
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Text(resultsTableSupport.results.year)
                .font(.headline)
            
            List (resultsTableSupport.results.final) { item in
                HStack{
                    if (item.rank == 1 || item.rank == 2 || item.rank == 3){
                        Image(systemName: String(item.rank)+".square.fill")
                            .padding(.trailing)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    } else {
                        Image(systemName: String(item.rank)+".square")
                            .padding(.trailing)
                    }
                    VStack(alignment: .leading){
                        Text(item.nazev)
                        DisplayMatchResultsIcons(model: item)
                        Text(item.points)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                            .font(.caption)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is from the ContentView.swift

```
    struct ContentView {
    @StateObject var resultsTableSupport = ResultsTableSupport()
@State private var selectedTab = 1
    }

extension ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
DisplayResultsTable(resultsTableSupport: resultsTableSupport)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                resultsTableSupport.loadResultsTable(competitionID: favoriteCompetitionID_1)
            })
            .tabItem() {
                Image(systemName: "list.bullet.rectangle.portrait")
                Text("Table")
                
            }.tag(2)
}
```

Comment: how do you scroll it?

Comment: Can you create a [mre]? Without one, this is unlikely to be solved.

Comment: The code doesn't show how the model is initialized. That's likely where the problem is.

Comment: you mentioned scrolling problems but you don't show the code where you scroll. You also get an error but you don't show us what it is.

Comment: @workingdog there is a List in the middle of DisplayResultsTable. Scrolling is auto handled in List, isn't it?

Comment: I see what you mean by scrolling now. One observation, why do you keep doing this irritating extension stuff, instead of doing what "normal" people do with just the view.

Comment: @workingdog I learned that from dimsumthinking and his Kickstart SwiftUI book. Regarding my issue I think that I need to re-read combine stuff, there must be an issue code handling data from the web

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the whole app just to find, that the problem wasn't with fetching data, but rather with ForEach loop itself.

Correct version is like this:

```
extension DisplayMatchResultsIcons: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack (spacing: -1.0){
                ForEach(0..<model.wins, id: \.self) {_ in
                    Image(systemName: "w.square.fill")
                        .imageScale(.medium)
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
            }
                ForEach(0..<model.loses, id: \.self) {_ in
                    Image(systemName: "l.square.fill")
                        .imageScale(.medium)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
            }

            ForEach(0..<model.draws, id: \.self) {_ in
                    Image(systemName: "d.square.fill")
                        .imageScale(.medium)
                        .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding of this issue is that ForEach can iterate only over a collection of items, which Int isn't. So this id: .self creates a collection on the fly.

Sidenote: I found this answer and solution in the SwiftUI Kickstarter book by Daniel H. Steinberg.